# Dragging and removing UIView from UIStackView but keeping it on its drop destination

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have bunch of views in a stack view and they are draggable. I want the dragged view removed from stack view after the drag drop action. And I want my stack view to be reorganised after drag drop action.

```
self.stackView.removeArrangedSubview(sender.view!)
```

This piece of code work but it is breaking this piece of code

```
sender.view!.center = referenceView.convertPoint(CGPoint(x: dropAreaLeft.midX, y: dropAreaLeft.midY), toView: sender.view!.superview)
sender.view!.frame = CGRectMake(sender.view!.frame.origin.x, sender.view!.frame.origin.y, sender.view!.frame.width * 0.5, sender.view!.frame.height * 0.5)
```

This code is for dropping the view and resizing it. Without "removeArrangedSubview" it works as expected but if I use "removeArrangedSubview" the view I am dragging/dropping is not being dropped on the correct point and it resizes itself.

Comment: How are you sizing the view that is being dragged?

Comment: It is being resized after dropping it with that line of code "sender.view!.frame = CGRectMake(sender.view!.frame.origin.x, sender.view!.frame.origin.y, sender.view!.frame.width * 0.5, sender.view!.frame.height * 0.5)"

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to subclass **UIStackView**
2. you need to **subclass the object type you are dragging**, and in that class
   create a delegate protocol for the subclass of the UIStackView to conform

   ```
     protocol objetMovedDelgateProtocol {
     func card(card:Cardview, didDragFromPoint initialPoint:CGPoint, toPoint   point:CGPoint)
           }
   ```

3.in the object you are dragging, from it's class, send the object center point, to the delegate to configure whether the point is inside the stackView or not and
what you want to do accordingly

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if delegate != nil {
            delegate?.card(self, didDragFromPoint: origin, toPoint: self.center)
        }
    }
```

in the delagete you do something like this:

```
func card(card:Cardview, didDragFromPoint initialPoint:CGPoint, toPoint point:CGPoint){

        if(!CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, point)) && card.isObjecInStackView{
            print("object was removed successfully from the stack view")
         ......
         ......
        }

       if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, point)) && !card.isObjecInStackView{
            print("object was added successfully to the stack view")
           let constraints = card.constraints
            card.removeConstraints(constraints)



            self.addArrangedSubview(card)
            self.bringSubviewToFront(card)
             card.isObjecInStackView = true

            ......
            ......

        } 
}
```

5. dont insert object with autolayout constarint into the StackView 
   it will start behaving unpredictabley
6. i have come to conclusion (like as you can see in the gif image)  that trying to do something like this with  StackView is very buggy, and unpredictable, so i think i'll pas out on the idea.. (because i also wanted to use it like that.)

[image: StackView]